# Text folding in richtextbox c#

Tags: c#, text, folding

my text is :

```
<Parag1 Level="One">
First text of parag1. Second text of parag1.
</Parag1>
<Parag2 Level="Two">
First text of parag2. Second text of parag2.
</Parag2>
<Parag3 Level="Footer">
First text of parag3. Second text of parag3.
</Parag3>
<Parag4 Level="Three">
First text of parag4. Second text of parag4.
</Parag4>
```

How can I create text folding for tags of text. example : start of folding is  `<Parag1 Level="One">` and end of folding is `</Parag1>`

tip : my text is in Arabic language(my text is rtl and my richtextbox is rtl). This mean that folding collapse lines (or to add the expand/collapse buttons) must in right of richtextbox.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: Please visit this link : [Folding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting) , I want this folding, but Right to left.

Comment: nice link... again my questions: what have you tried ? what is not working ? please show your source code modifications...

Comment: I want use FastColoredTextBox control in my form. but this control is left to right. I want change folding panel of text box in righ of textbox. source code is in link.

Comment: you mean: you did not try anything at all ? and expect someone on SO to do the complete modifications for you ?

Comment: I try to create markers and draw brackets highlighting and draw folding indicator, ... but all not correct in Rtl ! I want you suggest me component or control that support Rtl for folding text.

Comment: Is a commercial component an option ?